# mdbg can't debug my hello world program

Tags: c#, debugging, mdbg

In order to try out mdbg, I have the following simple hello world program:

```
// kkk.cs
using System;

class HelloMain
{
    static public void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello");
    }
}
```

Compile it with csc /debug kkk.cs, this yields:

```
kkk.exe
kkk.pdb
```

I then do (from the visual studio command line):

```
mdbg kkk.exe
```

or

```
mdbg !r kkk.exe
```

I got:

```
Error: The request is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070032)
```

Answer (score 8):

I know this question is super old, but I just ran into this and found the 'fix' for this problem. Adding here for any other Googlers..

I have two directories:

- C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\Mdbg.exe
- C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\x64\Mdbg.exe

Make sure you're launching the correct version (in my case, the **x64** version) and doing a 'Run as Administrator' when opening the command prompt.

Comment: I wanted the x64 build of mdbg so I followed the instructions above. But after I'd installed the SDK on my Win XP machine there was no .\x64 folder. When I repeated the SDK installation on a Win7 x64 machine the .\x64 folder was created and populated.

Answer (score 7):

Try
`csc /debug /platform:x86 kkk.cs`

You're running on 64-bit Windows. Mdbg is a 32-bit process and can only debug 32-bit processes.

Comment: It is possible to let mdbg debug x64 binaries? Or, should I use x64 version mdbg? If mdbg is only able to debug x86 applications, is that too limited?

Comment: I don't know if there is a 64-bit version of mdgb. I stopped trying to use it shortly after I encountered this same thing. VS is good enough for debugging managed apps 95% of the time. I use Windbg for that 5%.

Comment: Thanks for the help! It was very helpful! It seems that mdbg is indeed quite limited (if it is this case).

Comment: Argggghhhhhh! Stupid thing just bit me :(